# Symfony command --no-interaction is not working

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a setup with two different database connections, which also means two different entity managers. I'm trying to create a Symfony CLI command that calls the `doctrine:migrations:migrate` command with the `--em`, `--configuration` and `--no-interaction` options.
However, I struggle with the fact that despite having `--no-interaction` and `$input->setInteractive(false)`, I still get prompted with a confirmation.

Take a look at the code:

```
protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output) {
    $input->setInteractive(false);

    // some other code here

    $command = $this->getApplication()->find('doctrine:migrations:migrate');
    $arguments = array(
        'command' => 'doctrine:migrations:migrate',
        'version' => $version,
        '--em' => $em,
        '--configuration' => self::CONFIG_FILES[$em],
        '--no-interaction' => true
    );

    $migrationInput = new ArrayInput($arguments);
    $command->run($migrationInput, $output);
}
```

I tried pretty much everything that came to my mind. I couldn't see anywhere written that `--no-interaction` would not work with commands called from another command. Everytime I run that command I simply get the following:

```
WARNING! You are about to execute a database migration that could result in schema changes 
    and data lost. Are you sure you wish to continue? (y/n)
```

Which then prompts me to answer. Any idea?

Answer (score 24):

I found the problem. It was the fact that the `$arguments` variable was passed to a `new ArrayInput()`. I was only setting `InputInterface $input`'s `interactive` property to `false`, but to my other command called, I was passing a totally different `$migrationInput` which did not have the `interactive` property set to `false`.

So doing this:

```
$migrationInput = new ArrayInput($arguments);
$migrationInput->setInteractive(false);
$command->run($migrationInput, $output);
```

Solved the problem. I cannot figure out why the `'--no-interaction' => true` in my array is not doing it's job, though.

Comment: It's the little things that get us, not in documentation or such tiny informative text. Thanks, saved me losing more hair!